# Problem in getting all the files/dirs in a dir with contentsOfDirectoryAtPath

Tags: iphone, file-manager, nsdocumentdirectory

I have a zip file that I unzip it in a directory 'extract' under the Documents directory (the dir and its content is properly created). Then I would to do some stuff on each item in the new dir, dipendently if it's a file or a dir. I use the `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` method of the NSFileManager.
The problem is that the array `extractedItems` returns always null and I don't know what I'm wronging.

```
NSString *dirnameForUnzippedData = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"extract"];
NSString *dirpath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:dirnameForUnzippedData];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *extractedItems = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dirnameForUnzippedData error:NULL];

for (NSString *item in extractedItems) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking at the wrong path. Your code doesn't use `dirpath` (or your `documentsDirectory`).

As a side note, don't forget to `release` dirnameForUnzippedData after you're done with it - or just do `dirnameForUnzippedData = @"extract";` instead of the alloc/init.

Comment: Thanks, Eiko. You're right. It should be `NSArray *extractedItems = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dirpath error:NULL];`. If I would check if an item in the returned dir is a dir or a file, have I to use `[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:itemAbsolutePath isDirectory:&isDir]`?

Comment: @Objnewbie Yes, this sounds reasonable.